# Elementary trigonometry question

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\tan \theta$ = $n\tan \phi$ 
then the maximum value of $\tan ^ 2 (\theta - \phi )$ is?

The answer is $\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$.

 How do I solve to get the required answer?

Comment: Try using $tan(\theta- \phi)= \frac{tan(\theta)- tan(\phi)}{1+ tan(\theta)tan(\phi)}$

Comment: I did. But my solution's getting way too time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$k=\tan^2(\theta-\phi)$$ and write $$t=\tan\phi$$ so that $$k=(n-1)^2\frac{t^2}{(1+nt^2)^2}$$

Differentiating using the Quotient Rule gives $$\frac{dk}{dt}=(n-1)^2\frac{2t-2nt^3}{(1+nt^2)^3}=0$$

So the stationary value is given by $$t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Rightarrow k=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n}$$
You can check that this is maximum using the second derivative test.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which will leads to success.

Set $\theta=\arctan(n\tan \phi)$ Find $\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}$

then differentiate $\tan^2(\theta-\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ set the result equal to zero, you should be able to get the condition $$\frac{n\sec^2 \phi}{n^2\tan^2\phi+1}=1$$ then algebra and the sum formula you mentioned gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$$u=\tan(\theta-\phi)=\dfrac{(n-1)\tan\phi}{1+n\tan^2\phi}$$

$$\iff nu\tan^2\phi-(n-1)\tan\phi+u=0$$

As $\tan\phi$ is real, $$(n-1)^2-4nu^2\ge0\iff4nu^2\le(n-1)^2$$

If $n>0, u^2\le\dfrac{(u-1)^2}{4n}$

If $n<0, u^2\ge\dfrac{(u-1)^2}{4n}$

Comment: In the first case when n> 0, we get the required max. value for u^2. But in the second case, we get a negative value on the RHS for all n< 0. And u ^2 is always positive. So we don't really get a particular maxima here. So...? Please explain.